# Mongodb aggregate not grouping documents by date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following 3 documents in my MongoDB:

```
[Object_id: "tMSfNq9JR85XDaQe5"date: Sun Dec 07 2014 19:50:21 GMT+0800 (HKT)description: "Test" projectid: "S83NEGHnrefvfASrf"totalseconds: 22200__proto__: Object, 

Object_id: "FeyzdMosaXCht8DKK"date: Mon Dec 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)description: "444"projectid: "S83NEGHnrefvfASrf"totalseconds: 3660__proto__: Object, 

Object_id: "cCKByxSdQMHAsRKwd"date: Mon Dec 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)description: "555"projectid: "S83NEGHnrefvfASrf"totalseconds: 3660__proto__: Object]
```

I am trying to run the following aggregate pipeline on it to group the sum of `totalseconds` by `date` so that the end result will be something like shown below, yet each time I get the result as 3 records exactly just as input 3 documents...can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong / missing here? Thanks

```
var pipeline = [
  {$group:
        {_id:{"projectId":"$projectid", "date":"$date"},
         totalHrs:{$sum:"$totalseconds"}
        }
  }
];


 { "Date":"Sun Dec 07 2014 19:50:21 GMT+0800 (HKT)",
   "totalseconds": "22200"
 },
 { "Date":"Sun Dec 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)",
   "totalseconds": "7320"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are supplying here is the existing "date" value as part of the grouping key. It is exactly what it says it is and is likely to be very granular, i.e to the millisecond.

What you want here is to just use the "day" part of the recorded timestamp value in your date type field. For this you can use the [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) of the aggregation framework:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "projectid": "$projectid",
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
            "year": { "$year": "$date" }
        },
        "totalseconds": { "$sum": "$totalseconds" }
    }}
])
```

Or just use date math on your date objects and round the values to a day:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "projectid": "$projectid",
            "date": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ]},
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ]},
                        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "totalseconds": { "$sum": "$totalseconds" }
    }}
])
```

Either way, you want just part of the date field and not all of it. Otherwise there is nothing to actually group on unless exact time values are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So to group by the whole date field (as I had in the original query) without splitting it while grouping to day/ month / year the time need to be exactly the same in all dates...correct?

Comment: @MChan The point is that you do not want the "whole" date but only part of it. Unless you actually want to group date values that are "exactly" the same ( to the millisecond ) then you just want to extract something like the "day" part or "hour" or "minute". `2014-12-15 19:50:21` and `2015-12-15 00:00:00` are not equal and therefore not "grouped" together.

Comment: I fully understand what you mean, it is just that I am confused because I had already 2 documents with the exact same date: Mon Dec 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT) as you can see in my questions and they were not grouped together, so I am not sure was this because of using the full date/ time or something else?

Comment: @MChan It's because `projectid` is also part of your grouping key and it is not the same in the documents. Otherwise as I said, the actual date "value" is to the "millisecond" regardless of the stringified representation of it.

Comment: Since projectid is exactly the same in the 3 documents I have, then may be as you have explained there is a millisecond difference even between the two exact dates. Thanks