# C# MongoDB group (aggregate) by date

Tags: c#, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

All I want to do is group by the DateEntered and Role and get the counts.
The below code works, but groups on the full date down to to the second. I need to it to just group by the day (MM/DD/YYYY)

Also I would like to use Lambda expressions.

Thank you in advanced.

```
var group = new BsonDocument { 
            { "_id", new BsonDocument 
                { 
                    { "DateEntered", "$DateEntered" }, 
                    { "Role", "$Role" }, 
                }        
            }, 
            { "Count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } 
                            };

var result = _collection.Aggregate()
                .Group(group)
                .ToListAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Storing the date as yyyy-mm-dd might be easier.  Also you then follow the ISO 8061 standard. (http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer from this example
[Mongodb aggregate not grouping documents by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474865/mongodb-aggregate-not-grouping-documents-by-date?rq=1)

```
            var group = new BsonDocument { { "_id", new BsonDocument 
                                         { 
                                             { "Month", new BsonDocument("$month", "$DateEntered") }, 
                                             { "Day", new BsonDocument("$dayOfMonth", "$DateEntered") }, 
                                             { "Year", new BsonDocument("$year", "$DateEntered") }, 
                                             { "Role", "$Role" }, 
                                         } 
                                         }, { "Count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } };
```

Comment: This saved my life but what about group by only date part of it. Is there any way to achive this?